# python what does this mean in python matrix=[1][1:-1]

Tags: python, matrix

I have the following code in Python, but I do not know what it means.
Please help me understand this code. What is the goal of the matrix operation `[1][1:-1]`?

```
position_bins = pd.cut([-1.2, 0.6], bins=N_BINS, retbins=True)[1][1:-1]
velocity_bins = pd.cut([-0.07, 0.07], bins=N_BINS, retbins=True)[1][1:-1]
```

Comment: velocity_bins = pd.cut([-0.07, 0.07], bins=N_BINS, retbins=True)[1][1:-1]

Comment: position_bins = pd.cut([-1.2, 0.6], bins=N_BINS, retbins=True)[1][1:-1]

Comment: matrix [1][1:-1] means grab every element in the second row excluding the first element in the second row.

Comment: it's also exclusive of the last element

Answer (score 0):

That's a list slice

List slicing works as follows:

```
lst = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
lst[1:-1]
>[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
lst[1:]
>[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
lst[:-1]
>[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

In list slicing the lower bound is **inclusive** and the upper bound is **exclusive**. So in the case with this matrix, because indexing in python starts at 0, and the lower bound is inclusive, you are essentially taking the second element all the way to the second last element (see line 2 and 3 of the code I have above) of the matrix at column 2 (index 1, element 2).